# Stuck on Excel Max If

Tags: excel

Hey so I've run across a problem in excel that I've having a hard time to solving.

I currently have three columns of data

```
A       B    C
Apple   12   sold to
Mellon  3    sold to
```

Etc. my current issue is I need to find the max and the min and then return column C.

Currently I'm trying to use the below:

Where B1 is say "Apple" and H is the range of vales to look for the max in.

Does anyone have any good ides here? Currently its coming back #Name

```
 =max(MAX(IF($B$5:$B$71510=B1,$H$5:$H$71510))
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data more properly. It's difficult to understand what is column `C` and `H`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Office 365 you can use the MAXIFS function like this:

```
=MAXIFS($H$1:$H$71510,$B$1:$B$71510,"="&B1)
```

Here's Microsoft's documentation on the function:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

If you're using another version of Excel, you can try this instead.  Note that you'll have to enter this as an array function (cntrl-shift-enter instead of just enter.  It'll add braces {} around your function if you did it right)

```
=MAX(IF($B$1:$B$71510=$B1,$H$1:$H$71510))
```

More discussion on this method:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28589900/A-MAXIFS-function-in-Excel.html